# No permission to execute Netsuite suitelet script as administrator role

Tags: netsuite

I created a UE script that adds a button and loads in a CS script. The CS script in turn calls a SL script when the button is clicked.

I deployed the suitelet script to be executed as the administrator role with every role also being part of the audience.

My CS script:

```
https.post.promise({
    url: "https://"+domain+".app.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=687&deploy=1",
    body: params
})
.then(function (response){
    log.debug({title: 'Response',details: response});
    console.log('response', response);
})
```

The result I get is HTML telling me I have to login to access the page. When I actually take the URL and paste it myself in the browser however, it does work. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: What is the value of `domain`?  What do you get if you log what you're giving as the value for `url` in the `http.post.promise` method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `https.post.promise` method but even I once faced this exact error.

My suggestion here would be to use `url.resolveScript` method in your ClinetScript that would apparently call your Suitelet Script.

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;

var suiteletURL = url.resolveScript({
            scriptId: 'SUITELET SCRIPT ID HERE',
            deploymentId: 'SUITELET DEPLOYMENT ID HERE',
            params: {
                //If any
            }
});
window.open(suiteletURL, '_self', false);
```

Let me know in case of any issue in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was that Netsuite generated an external URL which required authentication always. The following code solved my issue:

```
    var suitletURL = url.resolveScript({
      scriptId: 'scriptid',
      deploymentId: 'deploymentid',
      returnExternalUrl: false
    });
```